# When to use $this and when simple variable

Tags: php, oop

I'd like to create the class that should manage my log. I begin to write this class. And I don't know when to use $this and when simple variable. Here is the code.

```
<?php
    class Log{
        private $name = "record.log";

        public function create($this->name){
            $handle = fopen($this->name, "a+");
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

Or should I use only `$name` instead of `$this->name?`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Thats not a class

Comment: $name will search for the variable within the scope of the function. If you want to use the variable defined outside of a function in a class you need to access it using $this->name;

Comment: You use `$this` when you want to access properties of the class/object. You omit `$this` when you want regular local function-scoped variables.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers Sorry, I've edited already.

Comment: I don't understand what `create($this->name)` is supposed to do at all. Even assuming you'd fix it to `create($name)`… do you want to take the name of the file to open as function parameter, or take it from the class's `$name` property? Which is it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not able to understand it from this page. It seems too difficult. I still don't understand if I used it well

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762 then.

Comment: @deceze that should create the file with name record.log.

Comment: So really there's no point in having a function parameter at all here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OOP:
`$this->name` is property of the object which is defined by the class and is accessible globally within the object.
`$name` is variable used inside the class method and is accessible locally only within the object method (a function)

Very briefly:

```
class myClass{

    private $name = "record.log";

    function myMethod(){
      $name = 'this exists only in the method myMethod()';
      $this->name; // this contains the 'record.log' string
    }

}
```

From outside the class you cannot access the variable `$name` defined within an object.

You can only access the property $name defined in the class but from outside of the object you must call it using the object name:

```
$obj = new myClass();
$log_file = $obj->name; // this would contain the string 'record.log'
```

However you defined the object property as private so the direct access will be restricted from outside of the object. To be able to access it you have to define getter/setter a methods that will handle read/write to private property.

```
// add to the class methods
public function getName(){
  return $this->name;
}

public function setName($value){
  // do some validation of the value first
  //...
  // then assign the value 
  $this->name = $value; 
}
```

So now you can access the object property $name from outside of the object using statements:

```
echo $obj->getName();  // prints record.log
$obj->setName('new.log');
echo $obj->getName();  // prints new.log
```

Comment: did you actually write all that out or took that from somewhere?

Comment: @ino Thank you very much. This I needed to know.

Comment: @MichalVlasák Happy to help, that's why  we are here ;) and good luck with OOP.